# concatenate multiple gifs, jpg and png to a video with background music

Tags: ffmpeg

i now tried for 2 hours to make a mp4 video with a few png, jpg and gif files all at a given seconds length including a background music but without success.

I tried multiple approaches from the internet and most of them gave me errors or the video was just the first image/gif for the whole video.

Can someone show me how to do this?